# How to write json files in Python 3 ignoring some lines?

Tags: python, json, api

I am using an API : https://app.omie.com.br/developer

The problem is that I need to put the requests inside a loop, to get all the pages in some methods. When I dump the file, I got an issue, which is: The json files open and close every loop, so I cannot put all of them into 1 only file.

Is there any way that I can ignore the first and last lines from every json response?

```py
import requests
import json

response = str(requests.get('https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/contapagar/?JSON={"call":"ListarContasPagar","app_key":"1560731700","app_secret":"226dcf372489bb45ceede61bfd98f0f1","param":[{"pagina":1,"registros_por_pagina":20,"apenas_importado_api":"N"}]}'))
if response != "<Response [200]>":
    print("Invalid Data")
else:
    response = requests.get('https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/contapagar/?JSON={"call":"ListarContasPagar","app_key":"1560731700","app_secret":"226dcf372489bb45ceede61bfd98f0f1","param":[{"pagina":1,"registros_por_pagina":20,"apenas_importado_api":"N"}]}').json()
    for i in range(1, response["total_de_paginas"] + 1):
        response = requests.get('https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/contapagar/?JSON={"call":"ListarContasPagar","app_key":"1560731700","app_secret":"226dcf372489bb45ceede61bfd98f0f1","param":[{"pagina":%s,"registros_por_pagina":20,"apenas_importado_api":"N"}]}'%i).json()
        if i == 1:
            mode = "w"
        else:
            mode = "a"
        with open("resultado.json", mode) as rs:
            json.dump(response,rs, indent=4)
        with open("resultado.json", "a") as rs: #I added this line expecting that would help fixing my problem, but it didn't
            rs.write(",\n")
        print("Page completed: %s" %i)
```

The Json File first and last lines looks like:

FIRST

```
{
    "registros": 20,
    "conta_pagar_cadastro": [
```

LAST

```
    ],
    "total_de_paginas": 11,
    "total_de_registros": 215,
    "pagina": 1
},
{
```

Where the last "{" is the start of the next page json response.

I need to ignore this lines when I run the code. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Two things I suggest: 1 is that you can do [`response.status_code`](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) instead of turning it to a string. 2 is that you should access the JSON and update the part that you want to save from the previous call with the part that you want to add to it. JSONs are just lists and dictionaries so you can add other list or dictionary items to them the same.

Comment: Open the file *before* the loop, then pass the same file object to each call to `json.dump`.

Comment: Don't think of this as ignoring certain lines of the response, as JSON isn't a line-oriented format. Instead, you are *collecting* the values of the `conta_paga_cadastro` element from each response.

Comment: I am preety noob on JSON... How can I dump the first and last lines then? Or how can I exclusively access the conta_paga_cadastro element (only)?

Comment: Oh, and Thanks for the suggestion @MyNameIsCaleb

Comment: I tried your solution @chepner, but the JSON still closing on the end. How can i drop only the last line?

Comment: If you are getting `,{` as the end of the response, the API is serving broken JSON.

Comment: I am not, as I mentioned on the question description... I appended that comma to try to fix the response. The next "{" you mentioned is the second requisition response...